# Error 25201 : UI Testing Failure

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode-ui-testing

While doing UITest i got this error.

I am using xcode 8.2.1

```
Assertion Failure: UI Testing Failure - Failure getting snapshot Error Domain=XCTestManagerErrorDomain Code=9 "Error -25201 getting snapshot for element <AXUIElement 0x7faf7b4173f0> {pid=84523}" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Error -25201 getting snapshot for element <AXUIElement 0x7faf7b4173f0> {pid=84523}}
```

I tried deleting DerivedData, Pods/, Podfile.lock and *.xcworkspace and running pod install afterwards. No luck. Still experiencing the error. First experienced in Xcode 7.3. Upgraded it and issue still persists.

Anybody who experienced the same thing? Kindly share here...

Any help will be Appreciated...Thank you.

Comment: What is the test doing when you get this error? Are you able to run the test successfully by hand?

Comment: i am trying to get the screenshot for screen with automated code. Yeah its successfull on hands. I thinks a bug from xcode...